# Getting all descendants IWebElements (using XPath) is too slow in Selenium

Tags: c#, linq, selenium

Well, I'm working with Selenium to scrape a webpage that has obfuscated class names (example `<div class="example-gHJkLM">...`)...

So I needed to create an extension method to get

```cs
public static ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> Descendants(this IWebElement element, bool hasChildren = false, int index = -1, string postAppend = "")
{
    var web = element.GetWebDriver(); // < 1ms
    var xpath = element.XPath(); // 5 ms

    return web.FindElements(By.XPath(xpath + "//" + (hasChildren ? "child::node()" : "*") + (index > -1 ? $"[{index + 1}]" : string.Empty) + postAppend)); // 64 ms
}

public static ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> GetNodesByContainingClass(this IWebElement element, string className,
    bool toLower = false, bool useFullHierarchy = false)
{
    return new ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>(element?.Descendants()
        .Where(n =>
            (toLower ? n.GetAttribute("class")?.ToLowerInvariant() : n.GetAttribute("class"))
            ?.Contains(className) == true).ToList()); // ????
}

public static IWebElement GetNodeByContainingClass(this IWebElement node, string className)
{
    return node?.GetNodesByContainingClass(className).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Example usage:

```cs
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            var welcomeMessage = messageBox
                .GetNodesByContainingClass(
                    "icon-", false, true)?
                .LastOrDefault();

            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($@"[Getting welcome message element] Ellapsed {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms!", Color.Yellow);
```

> - messageBox is a `IWebElement`
> - I'm using Colorful.Console package

And this is what I got:

[image: ...]

4 and 9 seconds to materialize a Where LINQ clause, seriously? I debugged the `element?.Descendants()` part and this has only 727 elements...

Can anyone guide me?

Also, I will be so thankfully if somebody suggests me a better approach to do this.

Comment: for start, try this `return new ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>(element?.Descendants().Where(n => n.GetAttribute("class").Equals(className, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));` check the performance, and report.

Comment: But I'm not looking for Equals comparison, I'm checking Contains.